# Camera running on iOS7 doesn't open and then crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

This code worked under iOS6.2; installed iOS7 and now crashes:

```
- (IBAction)bOpenCamera:(UIButton *)sender {

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  {

        customerCameraFlag = YES;  //  indicator so text fields are not cleared

        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = (id)self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        newMedia = YES;
}

}
```

I use the same code in two separate classes; neither one work.  The camera never opens, just crashes when the last line (newMedia = YES) has executed.  I have looked at all the entries in SO and Google, and found nothing that resembles this crash.  It apparently worked on iOS 6, but I am now unable to test it because I have gone to iOS7.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This is a bit unrelated, but what type is `customerCameraFlag`? If it's a `BOOL`, then the value should be `YES`, not `TRUE`.

Comment: Try enabling an exception breakpoint and add the exact exception text that is logged to your question.

Comment: @danielbeard: tried enabling exception breakpoints, but nothing in the code above causes the exception.  All of the standard delegate methods never get executed, so I assume this is what is causing it.  The exact exception text is EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @danielbeard EXC_BAD_ACCESS is not a thrown exception; it is a hard crash.   Spokane-dude should post the backtrace of the actual crash.

Comment: Interesting obversion:  when running the same app on the iPad under iOS7, *outside of the debugger* it works fine!  Go figure!  I'm going to give points, because as far as I'm concerned, it's a non-issue at this point.  Thanks everybody!  @bbum: can you rewrite your comment as an answer so I can close this?

Comment: @bbum: can you rewrite your comment as an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EXC_BAD_ACCESS is not a thrown exception; it is a hard crash. Spokane-dude should post the backtrace of the actual crash.*

---

**when running the same app on the iPad under iOS7, *outside of the debugger it works fine*!**

I'd bet it isn't working fine.  It only appears to be working, but something is still going wildly wrong, potentially corrupting user data.   I'd make figuring out what a priority.

Post the crash details.

---

OK -- crash is here:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b39c350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b31311e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b34f96e abort + 90
3   REDACTED.APP                    0x0006aa72 0x19000 + 334450
4   Foundation                      0x338a438c -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 164
5   Foundation                      0x338a4088 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 132
```

- That the main thread is dispatching to itself is pretty odd and indicative of a shaky, at best, concurrency implementation.

But wait!  The crash is actually further up Thread 0:

```
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b34f96e abort + 90
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3304cc __assert_rtn + 176
13  REDACTED.APP                        0x0001c3f2 0x19000 + 13298
14  UIKit                           0x34e4bd18 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 360
15  QuartzCore                      0x34bfabe0 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 108
```

Whatever is in frame 13 -- some layer delegate trying to draw -- is assert()ing.

Given that it is a failed assert in a drawing method, that should narrow things down considerably.